# Render variables in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried following this article:
https://thinkster.io/tutorials/rendering-variables-in-react

Is it because I am using an arrow function as component my code does not work? And how should I render a variable?

I get an error that the value `selectedValue` cannot be null.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  Button
} from "reactstrap";

const DropdownPaging = props => {
  var selectedValue = 10;

  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);

  function dropDownChanged(val) {
    selectedValue = val;
    alert(val);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <Button outline color="dark">
              &lt;
            </Button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Button outline color="dark">
              &gt;
            </Button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
              <DropdownToggle caret outline color="dark">
                {selectedValue}
              </DropdownToggle>
              <DropdownMenu>
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => dropDownChanged(10)}>
                  10
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => dropDownChanged(25)}>
                  25
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => dropDownChanged(50)}>
                  50
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => dropDownChanged(100)}>
                  100
                </DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </Dropdown>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropdownPaging;
```

---

After a reboot the event does not throw an error, but value is still not set?

Comment: How did you get that error?

Comment: Just copied your code into my project and everything works fine. Can you please tell us more how it did not work? Thanks!

Comment: You use onclick instead onchange event - maybe this is the problem...

Comment: I will paste when I am at a pc. Thanks for fast response.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I just plugged in your page substituting reactstrap components with regular divs and they worked fine. Alert worked on click and {selectedValue} returned 10 on load.

Comment: It is not  a select but the bootstrap dropdown. So onChange will not work. I just repooted my pc and the npm environment. The error I got was selectedValue cannot be null. I dont get this error anymore however the text is not updated when the value is set in the event function?

Comment: I watched a video about flux and redux is it because REACT does not support rendering changes without those frameworks?

Comment: @ThomasSegato React works just fine without additional state Management frameworks. They are often *useful*, but not *necessary*.

Comment: OK. It is a fairly simple sample, I must be doing something wrong. I will try to add an element that is not reactstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `selectedValue = val` does not tell the component it needs to re-render, it should be part of the state too:

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(10);

function dropDownChanged(val) {
  setSelectedValue(val);
}
```

As for "selectedValue cannot be null." you will have to post a stack trace and show where that is coming from as I can't see how it would happen in the provided code.

Comment: I used your sample and it worked! I am used to Angular so I am brand new to REACT. So every time you want to render a variable you need to use it like that? I thought it was an event thing when i watched the useState part. It is kind of strange you need two variables for this. However so many other cool stuff with REACY.

Comment: If you have state that is logically grouped together you can put it in an object e.g. `const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({ width: 0; height: 0 }).... setViewport({ width: 500, height: 500 })`. You can also use `useReducer` as an alternative but I prefer to put global state in reducers outside of the components and use useState for component level state.

Comment: Some people put all their state into one object e.g. `const [state, setState] = useState({ ...all your component state })` and `setState(state => ({ ...state, selectedValue: 99 }))` which is similar to how it would be if your component was a class

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks alot. I need some more experience with REACT before I can see what I prefer. But now it works, that is a start :D